# Unable to insert Geography Datatype into table - Azure Mobile service

Tags: javascript, sql, azure, azure-mobile-services

Hello all i have problem with mobile service backend script 
i cannot insert row into my table 
Full script :

```
function insert(item, user, request) {

var sessions = tables.getTable('sessions_res');

var point = "geography::STPointFromText('POINT('"+ item.longtitude + " " +     item.lattitude + "')' , 4326)";



console.log(point);
var queryString = "INSERT INTO sessions_res(id, restaurant_id, person_number ,budget , category , coordination) VALUES (?, ?, ? , ? , ? , ?)";


mssql.query(queryString, [item.id, item.restaurant_id, item.person_number, item.budget, item.category, point], {
    success: function () {
        request.respond(statusCodes.OK, {});
    }
});
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot insert" what is the result in the error logs?